# iPad with iOS6.x run iPhone app, screen size is wrong

Tags: ipad, ios6, screen, resolution

I found when run iPhone app under iPad with iOS6(the real device, not simulator), when check [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame = {{0,0}, {300,480}}, look this carefully, it's 300 not 320, of course the height should be 460(480-status_bar_height=460). I do not know how this happened.At the same time, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds value is right {{0,0}, {320, 480}}.

But when run in iPad simulator 6.1 [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame = {{0,20}, {320, 460}}, this is same when run app on iPhone 4 with iOS6.

Is this a bug? How can I get the correct screen resolution?

I found another strange thing. When run a protrait direction app on a landscape screen, navigation bar's height should be 44.0, but actually it is 32.0, this also occurs on iOS 6.1..